# Substitute 2N3055 with 2SC5200 in the John Linsley Hood 1969 amplifier circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, substitution

Can I substitute a 2SC5200 for the 2N3055, without any other modifications to the following amplifier circuit? Input voltage is 24 V and biased to run at 1.2 A.

[image]

schematic source : https://sound-au.com/jll_hood.htm

Comment: Yes, I do have have a pair of big heat sinks.. I will utilize them for sure..

Comment: @Ahsan - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link, for the source of that copied schematic. (And please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future). TY

Comment: Ahsan - Hi, I see you have added a [link](https://sound-au.com/jll_hood.htm) into the question, saying the schematic source is from that linked webpage. However I looked at that page, which has 10 figures on it. The schematic in the question does not seem to be any of those 10. Please can you confirm which one of the figures on that webpage, is that schematic copied into the question here? TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That design from Hood looks a little off, to me. Partly because I think the 2N3906 may *run out of gas* given certain drive cases. It also seems to be running very hot (a bit high on the quiescent current side of things) than is strictly necessary. But these are just quick mental sanity checks and I can't be sure without building one and/or running Spice on it. And I won't bother because I'd rather just offer something that I have tested.

As far as using the 2SC5200, I don't imagine problems in the following design I'll offer, as I've included a Miller cap to roll off circuit response. Using them below should be just fine. Just keep in mind that these devices are in a class-A amplifier and will be dissipating maybe \$15\:\text{W}\$ each. So give them some serious heat-sinking capacity.

Here's what I'd suggest trying:

[image]

I've bootstrapped the \$8\:\Omega\$ speaker as this turns \$R_1\$ into a semi-decent (and very cheaply used) current source. *(If you understand that \$C_{_\text{BOOT}}\$ will acquire a relatively stable voltage difference across it and accept that the \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ of \$Q_1\$ is also relatively stable, you can see that the voltage across \$R_1\$ should be similarly relatively stable.)*

\$R_1\$ will set the quiescent state of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$. If you increase its value, those two BJTs will run cooler. But depending on the voltage gain and signal input, that also could mean running out of drive current for the speaker and the resulting distortion. Lowering its value will run things hotter and provide more *steam* needed to avoid distortion. It's your call here. But feel free to make small adjustments to \$R_1\$, one way or another, per your needs. I've set \$R_1\$ to run things a little on the cooler end. But if you are driving the speaker hard, you may need to lower its value a little. Just FYI.

The voltage gain can also be changed by adjusting \$R_4\$. *(I've get the voltage gain to about \$16\times\$ or about \$24\:\text{dB}\$ as \$R_4\$ and \$R_3\$ form up a voltage divider that reduces the output signal by that much.)*

Per the instructions you see for Dr. Hood's design, you should adjust \$R_6\$ in the above schematic to get the collector node shared by \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ to about half the supplied \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$. This allows near the maximum output swing without running against the rails.

Answer (score 1):

Probably will work. 2SC5200 has an ft about an order of magnitude higher than the 2N3055 so there's something more of a possibility of RF oscillation than with real 2N3055s (which were real slugs).

Comment: How do I reduce the oscillation

Comment: There may not be any. @periblepsis shows a capacitor which will help. Keep leads short and bypass the supply close by with both reservoir and ceramic capacitors.